# Auto hide Notepad++ console dialog?

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ for development and the NPPExec plugin to execute the code. To execute, I press Ctrl-F6 to Execute the program. This invokes the console dialog to show the output of the compiler.

What I find annoying is that there is no way to toggle the console dialog off. There is an option `Toggle Console` ( <kbd>Ctrl-~</kbd> ) but this does not toggle it off, instead just transfers the focus back to the editor.

Is there a plugin or some work around to auto hide the console dialog ?

[image: notepad++]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not obvious, but you can [fix the "toggle console off" feature](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/forums/forum/672146/topic/5007038):

> In the Console, press F3 or F7 and check "Hide toggled Console" in the appeared bottom controls. (Or you can press Ctrl+T in the Console to get the same effect.)

You can also **prevent** the console from automatically appearing for a given script by including the following line at the top of your NppExec code:

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
```

Comment: also you can use `Ctrl +  ~` to switch in and out of the console window.

Comment: even better, add it on the bottom of the NppExec exec code; that way the console will briefly appear and auto-close on NppExec code end